# What is the use of extension of the real and complex field?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, field-theory, real-numbers

> What is the use of the extension of the real and complex fields to extended real and complex numbers (including $\infty$)?

If the extended real and complex sets are no longer fields, then what is the use of such extensions?

What is the application of the extended real and complex number sets over the real and complex field?

Comment: A subset of the real numbers might not be bounded by a real number but bounded in the extended real numbers

Comment: For the extended reals, the addition of $\pm\infty$ makes the order $<$ on the set "complete." Every set of extended real numbers has a supremum and infimum. This makes certain arguments and definitions easier. Both the extended reals and the extended complex numbers are "compact," a topological property that has a lot of convenience in general.